# JFilechooser's file name textfield

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I use JFileChooser and setSelectedFile such as "D:\outlook", and when show showSaveDialog, the file Name in JTextField is D:\  and the outlook folder selected, and I don't want like this, I want outlook folder selected and the file Name in JTextField is D:\outlook not D:\

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `setSelectedFile` use `setCurrentDirectory`.  Like so:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("D:\\outlook"));
    chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but what about feeding a 'relative to' component in that last line?  It is very rare there are no other UI elements on-screen when popping a JFileChooser.

Comment: @Andrew, in practice you would want to fill that in.  However, I meant for this example to run alone so that the OP could throw it in a main method and test it out. I will update the answer to make that more clear.

Comment: @jzd Has the detailed answer been shown, or it's still not ready?